# Issue with .htaccess configuration - Differences in behavior for HTTP and HTTPS requests

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having trouble with configuring my .htaccess file on my server. I would appreciate some help in understanding the difference in behavior between redirects for HTTP and HTTPS requests.

Here's the content of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# / -> src/public/index.php
RewriteRule ^$ src/public/index.php [L]

# /index.php -> src/public/index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ src/public/index.php [L]

# redirect http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?campaign=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?campaign=$1&id=$2 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /src/public/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /src/public/404.php

<FilesMatch config.ini|composer.json|config.php>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

My issue is that when a request is made directly to the site address via HTTP (i use https://httpstatus.io/), I get the full path to the file, for example /src/public/index.php, while when using HTTPS, the path is correctly displayed as /.

Could someone help me understand why the behavior differs depending on the protocol and how to fix it?

Here I add 2 screen:[image]
[image]

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Such an essential redirect should always happen _before_ any internal rewrites are made.

Comment: Not `php` related. Removing tag.

Comment: @CBroe can you more specific ? What i should change ?

Comment: The `# redirect http -> https` part should be the very first thing you do. (And then go test in a private browser window, or clear your history - otherwise you are likely to get fooled by already faulty earlier redirects, which your browser will probably have cached.)

Comment: @CBroe I changed the order in .htaccess and it works fine now. Big thanks : )!

Comment: But do you know _why_ the ordering is wrong? It's not because the HTTP to HTTPS rule should necessarily be first, but because the internal rewrites should be _later_. It's the internal rewrite that is causing the malformed redirect.

Comment: However, there are a few other issues with the directives as posted (apart from the ordering)... you potentially have a duplicate content issue with `/index.php` and `/` serving the same content. The former should be a canonical redirect. However, it would seem the later directives/rewrites are currently reliant on that earlier rewrite! The later rewrites at first look like you are rewriting to `index.php` in the root, however, that is then rewritten a second time by the earlier rewrite!? Do you have any public content outside of `/src/public/`?

Comment: @MrWhite no, only index is in /src/public/